# Which fields I should index in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been reading about the `add_index` method in Rails.

In a tutorial, I found this example:

```
class AddTitleToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

I have no idea why `[:user_id, :created_at]` are indexed and not the others.

How do I know which fields to index in a Rails application?

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends on your application, you mostly index foreign keys to improve Database performance. For instance next time you are going to search all the micropost that belong to a user, it will use the user_id index, and whenever you are searching all post created between certain times i'll use the created_at index. Indexes basically speed queries, you index based on what queries you are going to be doing constantly.

Comment: Sorry, what's **foreign keys** in plain English?

Comment: foreign keys are keys that are referencing tables outside of the table.

Comment: They are fields used by the database to maintain relations. The user_id is a foreign key, since it is the field that relates the micropost to the user. The field itself is like a pointer if you wish, it point to another table.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that everywhere there is a `belongs_to` relationship, including join tables, there should be a corresponding index. Some might call this overboard, but the performance difference between an indexed relationship and a non-indexed relationship is profound.

So, if a `User` has_many `Books`, then your migration should have a corresponding line `add_index: :books, :user_id`. If a `Book` has_many `Authors`, and an `Author` also has_many `Books` through a join table `BookAuthorings`, then there should be two indexes on `BookAuthoring` - one that covers `author_id`, and one that covers `book_id`.

I'd say that a good, solid 90% of Rails performance problems that I've run into stem from a missing index somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly index (as others said) the foreign keys and all other fields I intend to use for searching or sorting. So in you case I would add a key to at least the title field if you want to show the microposts in alphabetical order.

In case of the `content` field it may depend. If it contains a lot of text, you will most likely not do a simple sort or search but would want to do fulltext search. In this case a normal database index would not be of great help and you would have to use a fulltext search engine instead.